# Formatting text to be justified in Python 3.3 with .format() method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to Python and trying to work on some sample scripts. I'm doing a simple a cash-register type thing but I want to justify or right align the output so that it looks something like this:

```
subTotal = 24.95
tax = subTotal * 0.0725
total = subTotal + tax
paid = 30
change = paid-total
print("The subtotal was: $",subTotal)
print("The tax was: $",tax)
print("The total was: $",total)
print("The customer paid: $",paid)
print("Change due: $",change)
```

I know I could simplify this with a lot less print statements, but I just wanted it to be easier to see what I'm trying to do.

I want it to output something like this, notice that the dollar amounts are all aligned and that there is no space between the $ and the dollar amount. I do not know how to do these two things.

```
The subtotal was:   $24.95
The tax was:         $1.81
The total was:      $26.76
The customer paid:  $30.00
Change due:          $3.24
```

I tried reading the Python docs for the format method, but I didn't see any examples as to what format specifiers can be used to do certain things. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Should `total = subTotal + tax`?

Comment: Yes, sorry for that typo. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The amount can be formated like this:

```
"${:.2f}".format(amount)
```

You can add padding to a string, for example for a width of 20:

```
"{:20s}".format(mystring)
```

You can right align the string, for example with a width of 7:

```
"{:>7s}".format(mystring)
```

Putting all this together:

```
s = "The subtotal was:"
a = 24.95
print("{:20s}{:>7s}".format(s, "${.2f}".format(a))
```

Answer (score 4):

If you know the maximum sizes of the text and numbers, you can do

```
val_str = '${:.2f}'.format(val)
print('{:<18} {:>6}'.format(name+':', val_str))
```

It gets trickier if these aren't known in advance. Here's an approach, assuming `names` and `values` are lists:

```
value_format = '${:.2f}'.format
name_format = '{}:'.format
values_fmt = [value_format(val) for val in values]
names_fmt = [name_format(name) for name in names]
max_value_len = max(len(x) for x in values_fmt)
max_name_len = max(len(x) for x in names_fmt)
for name, val in zip(names_fmt, values_fmt):
    print('{:<{namelen}} {:>{vallen}}'.format(name, val,
        namelen=max_name_len, vallen=max_value_len))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
subTotal = 24.95
tax = subTotal * 0.0725
total = subTotal + tax 
paid = 30
change = paid-total

text  = [ 
"The subtotal was:", "The tax was:", "The total was:",
"The customer paid:", "Change due:"
]
value = [ subTotal, tax, total, paid, change ]

for t,v in zip(text, value):
    print "{0:<25} ${1:.2f}".format(t, v)
```

**Output**

```
The subtotal was:         $24.95
The tax was:              $1.81
The total was:            $26.76
The customer paid:        $30.00
Change due:               $3.24
```

You can also get the required spacing like this:

```
maxLen = max(len(t) for t in text)  
for t,v in zip(text, value):
    print str("{0:<" + str(maxLen) + "} ${1:.2f}").format(t, v)
```

Answer (score 2):

See http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#grammar-token-width

```
def myformat(name, value):
    return "{:<18} {:>6}".format(name, "${:.2f}".format(value))
print(myformat("The subtotal was:", subTotal))
print(myformat("The tax was:", tax))
print(myformat("The total was:", total))
print(myformat("The customer paid:", paid))
print(myformat("Change due:", change))
```

output:

```
The subtotal was:  $24.95
The tax was:        $1.81
The total was:     $26.76
The customer paid: $30.00
Change due:         $3.24
```

Answer (score 1):

```
subTotal = 24.95
tax = subTotal * 0.0725
total = subTotal + tax
paid = 30
change = paid-total
print("The subtotal was: %8s" % ("$%.2f" % subTotal))
print("The tax was:      %8s" % ("$%.2f" % tax))
print("The total was:    %8s" % ("$%.2f" % total))
print("The customer paid:%8s" % ("$%.2f" % paid))
print("Change due:       %8s" % ("$%.2f" % change))
```